# .NET 7 Maui on Windows not working for all targets of net7.0-windows

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

.NET 7 Maui on Windows is not working for all targets of `net7.0-windows`.

But .NET 6 Maui on Windows is working just fine for all targets of `net6.0-windows`.

Is .NET 7 not supported for Windows targets?

I'm getting this

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The project needs to be deployed before we can debug. Please enable Deploy in the Configuration Manager.

> Error DEP1600:
> The list of content files in the recipe file "C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\TestMauiApp1\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0\win10-x64\TestMauiApp1.build.appxrecipe" is missing or malformed.  TestMauiApp1

Any idea or resolution to this issue ?

Very strange .NET 6 Maui on Windows is working fine for all targets of windows

Only workaround so far is to use .NET 6 for Windows

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6398

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2789